# как не считывать сломанные строки из csv файла?

Tags: c#, csv

у меня есть csv файл где есть строки которые неправильно форматированы как не считывать их а просто вывести и просто дальше пойти считывать другие
вот код

```
var badRow = new List<string>();
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { 
                
                Delimiter = ";",
                BadDataFound = arg => badRow.Add(arg.Context.Parser.RawRecord)

            };
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:/Users/mnvp/Desktop/1.csv"))
            {
                using (var  csvReader =  new CsvReader(reader, config))
                {
                  var reacords = csvReader.GetRecords<PriceitemsClassMap>().ToList();
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте строки вручную, а не через `.GetRecords()` метод. То есть строку чтения меняете на `while` цикл с условием `csvReader.Read()`, а в нем читаете строку `var line = csvReader.GetRecord<PriceitemsClassMap>();`. Дальше уже от этого и идите, например оберните в `try/catch` и в случае успеха - добавление в колелкци, а случае ошибки, пропуск с логгированием.

Comment: Ну и также, судя по [этому](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/39736575e27b66ab6648027e3288e02ea1300613/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs#L1068), в конфигурации есть некий [ReadingExceptionOccurred](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/39736575e27b66ab6648027e3288e02ea1300613/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/Configuration.cs#L106), который можно переопределить, задав там свое действие при ошибки чтения строки (по умолчанию как видите "выкинуть ошибку" стоит.